# Is it impossible to use the item() method for getting of array item?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I learn JavaScript through the *"JavaScript & jQuery"* book by John Duckett (Russian translate).

Author writes two code examples of array item getting:

```
var colors = ["white", "black","custom"];
var el = document.getElementById('colors');
el.textContent = colors[0];
```

and

```
var colors = new Array("white", "black","custom");
var el = document.getElementById('colors');
el.innerHTML = colors.item(0);
```

In the article he wrotes that for getting of array item can be used `item()` method. But in the code sources he uses `colors[0]` instead of `colors.item(0)` in the second variant.

I see that `colors.item(0)` doesn't work. Is it wrong info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript arrays are specialised objects, which have a particular behaviour and a particular set of methods. `.item()` is not one of them.

There are many other JavaScript objects which also contain a collection of values. *Some* of these objects include an `.item()` method.

The thing is, even though these objects may have some similarity with arrays in that they contain a collection of values, they’re not the same. Arrays, have some features, and these other objects have some others.

To learn more about what JavaScript arrays *do* have, you can look at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

In principal, it would be possible to add an `.item()` method to arrays by adding to the Array prototype. However, it is certainly not a natural part of JavaScript arrays.

**Edit**

One of the important properties of the array is in how it is accessed: you can read, replace or create an item using the square brackets (`[]`). Non-array collections don’t have this feature, so the items need to be accessed with a dedicated method.

Another important property is that the `.length` property is automatically updated.

Comment: +1. Maybe add that `array` do not need an `item` method because they have dedicated syntax for it. Java mindset makes me sad.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it looks like a mistake in the book. The [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) class doesn't have an `item` method. `colors[i]` should be used to get an element at a specified index.